# How can I exclude certain values for curve fitting in R?

Tags: r

I have the following plot of some experimental data (see below). The red line is a fitting curve of the black dots, which are experimental values. Now, the first three dots at 0, 0.583, and 1.916 form a baseline and the next two, 2.083, 2.416, seem to be outliers. How can I program the fitting curve, so that it doesn't take into account baseline and outliers? At the moment, R is clearly trying to optimize also for those irrelevant values.

[image: plot]

```
x <-
  c(0,0.583333,1.916666,2.083333,2.416666,2.5,3.666666,5.916666,9,16.75,20)
y <-
  c(
    0.05464,0.05453,0.0544,0.18043,0.18151,0.12551,0.18792,0.2497,0.28359,0.31734,0.3263
  )

plot(x,y, ylim = range(c(0,0.45)), pch = 1)

fit <- nls(y ~ -p1 / exp(x) + p1, start = list(p1 = 1))

xx <- seq(0,20, length = 200)

lines(xx, predict(fit, data.frame(x = xx)), col = "red")
```

Comment: Simply ignore the values.  Since they are at positions 3 and 4 in your vectors use the following, plot(x[-c(3,4)],y[-c(3,4)], ylim=range(c(0,0.45)),pch=1) and replace any other instance of x with x[-c(3,4)] likewise for y.

Comment: This will only remove the points from the plot, but the fitting curve will stay the same. I actually want the fitting curve only fit the values that are not outliers or baseline. And when I use your y[-c(3,4)] for the lm, then it throws an error: `Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: ~`

Comment: Remove the baseline vales  from the data given to the fitting process, but there are no "outliers", only "data liers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid fitting the first 5 points use the `subset=` argument of `nls` giving a vector of the negative positions to exclude:

```
nls(y ~ -p1 / exp(x) + p1, start = list(p1 = 1), subset = -seq(5))
```

Note that this model is actually linear in its single parameter so we could use `lm` instead of `nls`:

```
lm(y ~ I(1-exp(-x)) - 1, subset = -seq(5))
```